# Curl returns bad results when passing variable to CURLOPT_URL

Tags: php, curl

I have a clue on my curl request, when i'm passing a variable to the CURLOPT_URL parameter i get bad values from response, when i hardcode the url curl returns good values :

```
class APi {
   public $this->url;
   public $this->token; // :)
   function __construct($url, $token){
       $this->url = $url;
       $this->token = $token;
   }

function getUsers(){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_PORT => "4000",
    CURLOPT_URL => $this->url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Postman-Token: 472244a4-af1d-4ca5-b26b-07f6b168c04b",
        "x-access-token:" . $this->token
    ),));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        print_r($response); //<== print bad values when CURLOPT_URL value is a variable
        return $response;
    }
  }
} // end of class api

// Init the class
$data = new Api($url, $token);
print_r($data->getUsers());
```

the $this->url is initialised from the constructor, when i paste the value of $this->url to postman i get good results but from code i get bad results.

Someone can helps me ?

thank you.

**====== SOLUTION ==========**

From advices of some of you i have to urlencode individual parameter value, and it works as excepted. Thanks for the var_dump tip to compare characters length.

Comment: have you tried tu encode url with the `urlencode()` ? http://php.net/manual/fr/function.urlencode.php

Comment: what does `var_dump($this->url)` print?

Comment: @Flyzzx CURLOPT_URL => urlencode($this->url), returns me "cURL Error #:Couldn't resolve host "

Comment: @apokryfos the var_dump returns string(344) "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/api/interims/all?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJkYXRhIjp7Il9pZCI6IjViNjE2Nzc3NzE3YjliMmQ1MTBmZGIwNiJ9LCJpYXQiOjE1MzM2NTMxODQsImV4cCI6MTUzMzczOTU4NH0.uPtQI1fDtcNfYDck2bjXdNlqkv1XT-Lf_0JumvAz06U&status=active&qualification=014&radius=50000&userLat=48.815573&userLng=2.2241989999999987"

Comment: Two more questions: 1) Does counting the characters in the URL result in 344 characters ? (the value that var_dump prints)? 2) When you try it with a hard-coded URL is it the exact URL that `var_dump` printed?

Comment: @apokryfos, i think yes because when i paste the url to postman i get good results,

Comment: Postman is not the same as cURL. For example you have `CURLOPT_PORT` as an option here and have the port in the URL. You can't do that in postman. Is that ok to do with cURL? I don't know.

Comment: @apokryfos the var_dump of hard coded url is 324 :), why this difference?

Comment: 324 is less than 344 so there's 20 characters to account for. Are there any `\0` characters in there or any zero-length spaces? Those need to be cleaned. As @Flyzzx suggests you should use `urlencode()` but the problem is you can't really use it directly on the string so you may need to [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) first, properly clean it up and encode it, and then reconstruct it.

Comment: @apokryfos could you give me an example ?

Comment: You need to `urlencode` individual URL paramter *values* but not the entire URL itself.  e.g. `$url = 'https://api.example.com/resource?x=' . urlencode($x) . '&y=' . urlencode($y);`  See also [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query) which may help here.

Comment: Hi, thank you, i already use http_build_query, i'll try to urlencode individual parameters

Comment: SOLVED, i urlencode individual parameter value as said above. Thank you